# Which of ppp, tcp, rtp and tls are connection-oriented protocols?

Tags: networking, tcp, ssl, rtp, ppp

There is not much to say here - I'd like to ask which of these for protocols:

- Point to Point Protocol
- TCP
- Real Time Protocol
- TLS

...are connection-oriented and which of them are reliable?

Comment: Please be more specific with what you mean by "connection". Is this a quiz question?

Comment: No, it's not. I just want to create kind of hierarchy in my mind, that's why I'm asking. I mean connection-oriented as written here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection-oriented_protocol

Comment: if you saw that page, then you should know the answer for *at least* one of those protocols.

Comment: That's true, I just wanted to be ensured by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocols you list are at different communication layers, so a direct comparison doesn't necessarily make much sense.  TLS and RTP are above the transmission layer, while PPP is a link layer protocol, and these usually (not always) don't care about connections in the sense e.g. TCP does (though link layer protocols might provide services to make sure frames are not lost and arrive in order).  To make a long story short, only TCP from your list is a connection-oriented protocol.  TLS and RTP work both on top of TCP and UDP.